# TypeError: Ti.App.getArguments is not a function

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am using Ti.App.getArguments() in my android app in titanium appreciator studio but i am facing below error every time.[Getting error given in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzZqL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the API documentation https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-method-getArguments the `getArguments()` function is only available on iOS and judging from you command line argument you are compiling for Android.
A solution for Android is:
`On Android, fetch the Ti.Android.rootActivity object and read its intent property to retrieve the parameters used to launch the application activity.`